# fbjs: get uid of current loggedinuser

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

i have to use fbjs for my current app. 
i was using the `api.requireLogin` function earlier but then i looked over at the docs and found the function has been deprecated and suggested to use `FB.Connect.requireSession()` instead.

I wanted to know how do i get the uid of the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean Facebook Connect and not FBJS as they're different things. ([FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS) only runs inside FBML apps, Facebook Connect runs outside in iFrame apps and external websites.)

But in Connect:

[`FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser();`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser)